# WCF Service @ SharePoint 2010 TimeOut

Tags: wcf, time-out, object-model

I have been developing on SP 2010 for a while now.  Mostly I have been working with the Client Object Model.

Though I am at a point where I need to read out the UserProfiles from inside SharePoint.

I see no other way to do this than to make a custom WCFService and deploy it to SharePoint.

So that is what I did. I made an "Empty SharePoint Project" and added the mapped "ISAPI" folder.

The code from the WCF Service:

```
public string GetUserByName(string _name)
    {
        string server = "http://esddev72";
        UserProfileManager profileManager;
        string s = "";
        string u = "";
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
        {
             using (SPSite site = new SPSite(server))
             {
                 SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
                 profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context, true);
                 s += "AccountNames: ";
                 u += "firstNames: ";
                 foreach (UserProfile profile in profileManager)
                 {
                     if (profile["AccountName"] != null)
                     {
                         s += profile["AccountName"] + " - ";
                     }
                     if (profile["FirstName"] != null)
                     {
                     }
                 }

             }
        });
        return s;
    }
```

This service gives a TimeOut error...
When I delete the following line the TimeOut is fixed

```
if (profile["FirstName"] != null)
                     {
                     }
```

So I can only read out the AccountName...
Does anyone know a solution to this?

I've read things about putting the timeout times higher, but it didn't work for me... Or maybe I did someting wrong, so if you could explain that part as well ;)

Thanks !

Comment: Frederik: I saw your moderator request and I just tweeted a link to this for you.  Sorry I don't have any idea about the answer; hopefully someone else will.  Also try the MSDN Forums if you don't get and answer here.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I would realy want to know what is going wrong.
I needed it in a project but since it kept failing i replaced it with an asmx webservice. But still, it should have to be possible to get a wcf service to work i guess...

Answer (score 1):

Well at this moment i solved it by using .asmx webservices...
But still no idea how to solve the WCF TimeOut tho...

Answer (score 0):

Try PropertyConstants.

http://www.sharemuch.com/2010/03/29/creating-new-sharepoint-2010-user-profiles-programatically/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilemanager.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i have already tried PropertyConstants and it did not work...
I'll say again: The code IS working when i run it through a console application.
But i need to get the UserProfiles in Silverlight so i have to use a WCF Custom Service to fetch the UserProfiles.

And its here that it is going wrong ...

Answer (score 0):

Did you deploy the service in the recommended SharePoint way? i.e. write the code and deploy a .svc file that references that class but uses the out of the box SharePoint factory i.e:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="YOURCLASS, YOURASSEMBLY, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=TOKEN" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Yould also decorate your service class wit the following attributes

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
[ServiceBehavior(Namespace = "http://servicenamespace/", IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true)] // IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults not required of course
[BasicHttpBindingServiceMetadataExchangeEndpointAttribute]
```

By doing this the service will be running as if it were in SharePoint and you can even use `SPCOntext.Current`. Security is also automatically done because it will be run by SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

```
<basicHttpBinding>

<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_myWCF" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" openTimeout="00:20:00" closeTimeout="00:20:00"

sendTimeout="00:20:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">

<security mode="None" />

</binding>
```

and in the web.config of the WCF service:

```
<bindings>

<basicHttpBinding>

<binding name="Binding1" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00" openTimeout="00:20:00" closeTimeout="00:20:00"

maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>

</basicHttpBinding>

</bindings>
```

the web service method still times out after 1 minute and raises an exception in the client.

Also the

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

Comment: So you're suggesting the solution is to increase the timeout to be 20 minutes?